# Install Screenshot Icon

Tags: icons

How do I install the Screenshot icon from software to Dock in Ubuntu 18.04? I know I can access it in software but I would like a quicker way to access it.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the Screenshot application to the Dock just like any other application. Open the application overview, search "Screenshot". As you start to drag the icon to the left, the Dash will reappear. Drop the icon on the Dash in between two icons already on the dock, and it will be pinned.